# C exercise bool type segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, boolean

> I Don't know Why But this code give me a Segmentation Fault,I'm trying to understand , this exercise Basically check if the numbers insert by user in the first array(A) Has some Zero and Duplicate numbers, and if that is true, The program will not insert that zero and duplicate in the next array (B).

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

 int main () {
int a[19], b[19], i, j, N, A = 0;
  
  do{
      printf ("How many numbers? : ");
      scanf("%d", &N);
    }while (N > 19);
  
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      printf ("Insert the number %d : ", i + 1);
      scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    
    bool zero= false;
    bool idem= false;
    
 for(j=0;j<N;i++){
    if(a[i]==a[j])
        idem= true;
      if(a[i]==0)
        zero= true;
    }
    if(idem==false){
    b[A]=a[i];
    A++;
    }
    if (zero== false){
    b[A] = a[i];
    A++;
    }
    
 for (i=0;i<A;i++){
        printf ("%d", b[i]);
}

 }
 
}
```

Comment: Try to break the problem down into smaller pieces- comment out parts that aren't necessary to make the error occur, as long as the data is still "supposed to be" valid up until that point, and you'll be able to figure out which piece of code is causing issues.

If you break it down further, it will also make it easier for us to answer. A tip for narrowing it down is to split it into functions, or to pre-initialise data that you intend to work with, as if it were the results of an earlier computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
  int main () {
  int a[19], b[19], i, j, N, A = 0;
  bool idem,zero;
  //Input number of elements
  do{
    printf ("How many numbers? : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
  }while (N > 19);
  //Input array
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf ("Insert the number %d : ", i + 1);
    scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  //Checking duplicates and zeroes
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){ //for
    zero= false;
    idem= false;
      
  for(j=0;j<N;j++){
      if(a[i]==a[j]&&i!=j){  //add a condition (&& means AND). if j=i obviusly a[i]  = a [j]
        printf("idem found\n"); //printf debug
        idem= true;}
  }
  if(a[i]==0){
    printf("zero found\n"); //printf debug
    zero= true;}
      
    //a[i] mustn't be either duplicated nor zero. Not only one of this conditions.
    //Use the logical AND &&
    if(idem==false && zero==false){ 
    b[A]=a[i];
    A++;
    }
  }
     
  //output array
  //Must be collocated outside the "main for". I don't need to make an output in every iteration.
  printf("The B array is:\n");
    for (i=0;i<A;i++){
    printf (" %d ", b[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats's your inner for cycle *for(j=0;j<N;**i**++)*
You have to increment j not i. This way  for(j=0;j<N;**j**++){

If you increment i you will exceed the array lenght making happen a segmentation fault

Comment: Ok now the if of a[i] ==a[j]  doesn't work and the program shows me the idem numbers, what should I do?

Comment: I add an answer with working code. Because there are many problems in your.
Look at the comment